# 301 Redirect from all index.asp? Queries to Homepage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to use `.htaccess` to redirect all pages that contain the `index.asp`? query to the homepage.

for example:

```
index.asp?currentPage=1411&cat2=seating
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect 301 /index.asp http://example.com
```

Comment: Thankyou this did work as a redirect. The only issue being it keeps the query in the URL and this would cause a duplicate content issue.

Is it possible to redirect and remove the ?query after the url?

Comment: Managed to fix this with the rewriterule

`RewriteRule ^index.asp http://www.example.co.uk/? [L,R=301]`

Thanks for your help